# Search - Calculating relevance based on how close keywords are to the far left?

Tags: python, django, lucene, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm currently using **ElasticSearch**, **Python/Django** and **Django-Haystack**.

I wish to have items rank based on how close keywords are to the far left.

---

Example

Items are

- `Jeff is friends with John, Laura and Edward`
- `Laura is friends with Francis, Drake, Jessica and Jeff`
- `Edward is friends with Laura, Jeff and Jeff`

---

If Jeff is the query I would like to have the following result

1. `Jeff is friends with John, Laura and Edward`
2. `Edward is friends with Laura, Jeff and Jeff`
3. `Laura is friends with Francis, Drake, Jessica and Jeff`

---

But I get this:

1. `Edward is friends with Laura, Jeff and Jeff`
2. `Jeff is friends with John, Laura and Edward`
3. `Laura is friends with Francis, Drake, Jessica and Jeff`

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please let me know whther my answer was helpful or not?

Answer (score 1):

When you query elasticsearch you get back the `_score` field for each document, and if you add the `explain=on` parameter to the url you get back an explanation regarding the score as well, through which you can understand why a document is on top or not.

Anyway, I guess your first document gets the highest score because it contains the word Jeff twice. The third document is the last one because the text field is longer than the others and it contains only a Jeff match. This is how the Lucene score is computed. You can tweak it, for example disabling the fact that the length of the field influences the score, but you can't completely change the logic behind it unless you're willing to writing some Lucene code. You could do it writing your own Lucene `Similarity` implementation and plug it in elasticsearch with a custom `SimilarityProvider`. Have a look at [this](https://github.com/tlrx/elasticsearch-custom-similarity-provider) example.